# arm64 assembly convert int to string

Tags: string, assembly, printing, integer, arm64

I'd like to convert an integer to a string (`char *`) so I can print it - in pure aarch64.
This is what I came up with:

```
        ; adr x20, ->result         // x20 = char *

        ; mov x14, 0                // x14 = digit counter
        ; mov x15, 12345            // x15 = number to convert
        ; mov x16, 10               // x16 = divisor

    ; ->divide:
        ; udiv x17, x15, x16        // x17 = quotient
        ; msub x18, x17, x16, x15   // x18 = remainder
        ; add x18, x18, 48          // x18 = remainder as char
        ; strb w18, [x20, x14]      // put char in char *
        ; add x14, x14, 1           // x14 = digit counter
        ; mov x15, x17              // x16 = remaining number to convert
        ; cbnz x17, ->divide        // repeat until quotient is zero

    ; ->result:
        ; .byte 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Values are hardcoded because I feel it as a comfortable starting point.

This is  the logic I'm trying to follow:

1. Divide the number by 10: the remainder is the last digit;
2. Add 48 to the remainder, so I get the last digit as a ascii char;
3. Write that char to a buffer (incrementally);
4. Repeat until the quotient becomes zero.

However, the code immediately occurs into a segmentation fault on this instruction `strb w18, [x20, x14]`.
Using `gdb`, it seemed everything was correct: `x18` had `53` (`5` - the last digit of `12345` - + `48`).

However, I guess I still don't get how `str(b)` works.

First of all, `adr x20, ->result` will load the pointer to `result` (a pointer to `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, the buffer) at `x20`, let's say `0x7fb697d40c`.
Then, `strb w18, [x20, x14]` should take the least byte of `w18` (`53` in the first round) and put it at `0x7fb697d40c` + the content of `x14` (`0` in the first round).
So I expect `0x7fb697d40c` to point to `[53, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

However, `SIGSEGV` occurs and I don't know why.
What am I missing?

Edit
Here it is the source code using the usual syntax.

```
_start:
    mov x14, #0
    mov x15, #12345
    mov x16, #10

    adr x20, result

divide:
    udiv x17, x15, x16
    msub x18, x17, x16, x15
    add x18, x18, #48
    strb w18, [x20, x14]
    add x14, x14, #1
    mov x15, x17
    cbnz x17, divide

result: 
    .byte 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Solution:
As Nate pointed out in the comments, the memory range where the code was located was not writable.
Since I didn't want to involve `mprotect` to alter the permissions, I just ended up using the stack.

Comment: Instead of commented-out code, could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that could be copied/pasted into a file (say,  `str.s`), and assembled/linked as is ? this would greatly facilitate answering your question.

Comment: @Frant I forgot to say that I'm assembling that code at runtime using dynasm-rs, that's why I'm using its syntax. I'll update the question asap

Comment: Are you sure that `result` is being placed in a writable data section?  Normally you would expect to see `.data` before that label.

Comment: @NateEldredge Sorry, I forgot to remove those two `ldr` lines. I updated the question. However, you are correct, the data section I'm trying to store to is not writeable. Thanks!

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [Segfault when writing to string allocated by db \[assembly\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25124591) but that's about shellcode so the answer doesn't really suggest putting writeable static data in .bss or .data.